# Is triple monitor possible with Intel HD 3000?

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I am considering buying a new PC, with Intel HD 3000. I have 3 monitors, the MB has VGA, HDMI and DVI outputs. Is it possible to work with 3 monitors in such a system (with 12.04 or 11.10)? Does anyone have any experience to share on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Intel's FAQ](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-031040.htm) on the HD 3000 the answer is no.

> Can I output video to three display devices, not just two? No. Intel®
>   graphics products can output to one or two display devices at the same
>   time. More than two display devices can be physically connected, but
>   only two display devices can be used at any time.

Comment: Thanks! Will this be also true for the new Intel HD 4000?

Comment: Not sure about the HD 4000

Comment: I read Intel HD 4000 specification and there is mentioned only one display, not even two.

Comment: Update: HD4000 with 3rd generation Core series does support 3 monitors. For a complete list of chipsets that support it, see http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm#Q1.

Of course, if you are driving that many monitors you should probably get a discrete graphics card.